# Downloading a large site with wget

Tags: linux, command-line, internet, download, wget

I'm trying to mirror a very large site but wget never seems to finish properly. I am using the command:

```
wget -r -l inf -nc -w 0.5 {the-site}
```

I have downloaded a good portion of the site, but not the whole thing. The content does not change fast enough to bother using time-stamping.

After running overnight, this message appears:

```
File `{filename}.html' already there; not retrieving.
File `{filename}.html' already there; not retrieving.
File `{filename}.html' already there; not retrieving.
File `{filename}.html' already there; not retrieving.
Killed
```

Does anyone know what is happening and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [the '`-m`' option](http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_mirror,_spider,_or_archive_a_website)?
it is a short cut for,

> -N -r -l inf --no-remove-listing

You can also experiment specifically with the site using a deeper URL for a limited set of files and avoid fetching parent paths with,

> -np

Comment: I have not tried -m because it is not compatible with -nc and i dont want to overload the servers by downloading every single page when I already have most of them.
I have also tried -np and it made little difference for this site.
I will try to use a series of deeper urls.

thanks.

Comment: @Evan: `-m` works in a similar way to `-nc` -- it will not re-download files unless the server has a newer version. Most web servers support those checks.

Comment: Thanks. I have written up a script to use the -m flag and wget each level 2 directory separately, sleeping between each directory. I'll run it tonight and update the question/answers.

Comment: You might want to look at the `-w` option too.

Comment: Downloading each subdirectory separately solved the problem. I tried to get the entire site with one large recursive wget but it always used my entire 4GB of memory. In the end, I got everything 2 levels deep with -l 2, and ran a for loop to perform a recursive wget on all the directories in the site with this command:

wget -m -w 1 --random-wait -np www.fakesite.com/directory